# Installing qutebrowser - Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated

Tags: python, gallium

## Running qutebrowser -  Calling _exit(1)

### Useful information

`python3.5` and `pip3.5` are installed by default on `gallium OS 16.04`

I tried installing qutebrowser on gallium OS. As the operating system is based on xubuntu, I followed these steps:

https://qutebrowser.org/doc/install.html#_ubuntu_16_04_lts_linux_mint_18

I used `pip3.5` to install all the missing packages the python program needed.

### Problem

When I run qutebrowser using:

```
$ python3.5 qutebrowser.py
```

I get an error stating: `Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated`.

This error was posted on a thread but has not been resolved yet: https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/3731.

Comment: That issue was closed because "...and you still haven't answered any of the questions we asked above ". If you have the same problem, file a new bug, or reopen that one, and make sure to answer all the questions they asked the previous reporter.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm not sure how anyone on SO, or anyone else but the qutebrowser team, can help you with a bug in qutebrowser, unless you're asking how to ignore them, learn their code, fork it, and fix it yourself.

Comment: My issue is different but it can be related to his as we are both using chromebooks - My error output is: `Could not find QtWebEngineProcess`

Comment: @abarnert Found a fix anyways, refer to accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem was: `Could not find QtWebEngineProcess`

After doing more research, I found this link:

https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/3662

This solved the issue:

As **sudo** or **root**:

```
$ pip3.5 uninstall
$ pip3.5 install --user PyQt5==5.10.0 # Do not specify username
```